# Why does Feynman say “That is all there is to the theory of relativity – it just changes Newton’s law by introducing a correction factor to the mass”

Tags: special-relativity

In the Feynman Lectures, he lays out how in special relativity, the mass is adjusted by a factor of $\sqrt{1 - v^2 / c^2}$ and then writes:

> For those who want to learn just enough about it so they can solve problems, that is all there is to the theory of relativity – it just changes Newton’s law by introducing a correction factor to the mass

Does Feynman mean that you can derive the other phenomena described in special relativity (time dilation, length contraction) from only this correction to the mass? If so, how? If not, what other postulates are necessary?

Comment: Personally, I never understood what Feynman meant by this quote. It isn't really true.

Comment: Feynman's biggest blunder ;)  I'd say that makes him personally responsible for about 50% of the answering/commenting work in the relativity section . . . . didn't realize he came right out and said that!

Comment: If I remember correctly Einstein himself discouraged thinking that the mass of an object increases and that it’s better to think of the inertia of the object increasing. For a given force, as the object approaches the speed of light, the acceleration decreases approaching zero. Otherwise Newton’s second law predicts the velocity eventually becomes infinite

Comment: @BobD but how do you define mass? Inertia is a great way, so in a sense it is true...

Comment: @OfekGillon IMO inertia a property of mass and I define inertia as resistance to change in motion. To me, it feels more natural to say an object's resistance to change in velocity increases as you approach the speed of light than to say the mass of an object increases as you approach the speed of light. But again, it's just my opinion.

Comment: @BobD Yeah ok you defined inertia, but how do you define mass? What is a kg?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The claim is wrong because Newton's second law does *not* become $F=m \gamma a$.

Comment: Did you mean second law?

Comment: It works if you put it as $F=\frac{dp}{dt}$ where $p=mv=\frac{m_0v}{\sqrt{1-\frac{v^2}{c^2}}}$ and $m_0$ is the rest mass

Comment: @RyanParikh I agree but the claim suggests otherwise.

Answer (score 2):

Relativistic kinetic energy $$K_{rel}=mc^2\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-(v/c)^2}}-1 \right)$$
is not obtained
from [Newtonian] kinetic energy $$K_{nr}=\frac{1}{2}mv^2$$
replacing $m$ by $m\displaystyle\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-(v/c)^2}}$.

Answer (score 1):

It seems like the claim is, that though the notion of the `relativistic mass` is misleading - and not in the spirit of general covariance, where one speaks in terms of invariant or entities, transforming according to a certain represantation of Lorentz group, if one employs this definition and works with the Newton law - one would obtain the correct results.

However, in General relativity such an interpretation would produce wrong results - like the deviation of light ray in gravitational field would differ by a factor of 2 from the correct answer.

Comment: Feynman was talking about special relativity only.

Comment: @my2cts yes, it is mentioned explicitly, i just wanted to make a remark