# Can $p=mv$ be used for speeds close to $c$?

Tags: special-relativity, momentum, mass, velocity

Can I use the formula $p=mv$ for a particle which is travelling at a speed which is very close to the speed of light?

Comment: Why does this question has so many downvote. This question doesn't deserve that.

Comment: @RanjitKumarSarkar exactly, it is a clearly stated, and admits a yes or no answer. Just because the answer is obvious to non-beginners doesn't make it at poor question....even then it has a "yes" and a "no" answer, both of which are correct.

Comment: Hi Dylan Rodrigues. Welcome to Phys.SE. What is your definition of $m$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you can't.

Instead you need to use the [relativistic momentum](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/Relativ/relmom.html)
$$p=\frac{mv}{\sqrt{1-\frac{v^2}{c^2}}}$$
where $m$ is the [invariant mass](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Invariant_mass) (formerly also called *rest mass*).

You see, that this formula will result in $p\to\infty$ when $v\to c$.

Comment: Also note that when $v^2/c^2$ is small, you can Taylor expand and get $p = mv(1+v^2/2c^2+\cdots)$ which is neat.

Answer (score 4):

No you can't.  You need to use $p = \gamma m v$ where $m$ is the rest mass.

For reference: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Energy%E2%80%93momentum_relation

Comment: Adding a link https://socratic.org/questions/how-to-prove-m-m-0-sqrt-1-v-2-c-2 .

Answer (score 0):

Yes, **but** m is the relativistic mass.  In terms of the rest mass $m_0$, $m = m_0/\sqrt{1 - {v^2/c^2}}$.

Comment: "Relativistic mass" is a deprecated concept these days. We should not be encouraging students to you use it. It will not do them any favours come exam time.

Comment: It's easy to get in trouble, with, for example, relativistic kinetic energy ( https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/595075/148184 ) unless you are careful (https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/597577/148184 )